# Copy migration scripts created inside docker to outside database

Tags: database, docker, migration, flask-migrate

I am currently working on a project where I use Postges inside a Docker and manage it via Flask-Migrate but only during development. 
My goal is to use a database directly on a VPS in production.

Can I create migration scripts on the Docker databse and then copy them to run on the VPS database?

Comment: What happens if you try?  Why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration scripts will be stored with your source code, not inside the Docker container where the database is. So it really does not matter, as long as you set the database connection URL properly you can generate and apply the migrations on any supported database, be it hosted on a container or a VPS.